# Angular 8 module routing

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular8

My angular 8 app is fine until I put another component declaration in my shop.module.ts and shop.routing.ts

My **app.routing.ts**

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'shop',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: FrontendPanelLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'shop',
        loadChildren: './shop/shop.module#ShopModule'
      }

    ]
  }

];
```

My **shop.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    GlobalModule,
    SlickModule.forRoot(),
    NouisliderModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}),
    RouterModule.forChild(ShopRoutes),
  ],
  declarations: [
    ShopListingComponent,
    ShopDetailComponent  //I newly put this one.
  ],
  providers: [
    ShopService
  ]
})
export class ShopModule { }
```

My `shop.routing.ts`

```
export const ShopRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ShopListingComponent
  },
  //I newly put this one.
  {
    path: 'shop/detail',
    component: ShopDetailComponent
  }
];
```

My App is totally fine when I remove **ShopDetailComponent** from both **shop.module.ts** and **shop.routing.ts**. When I put again **ShopDetailComponent** then app is running with blank page without error. Is there something wrong in my routing declaration?

Comment: Change `path: 'shop/detail'` to `path: 'detail'` and try.  The prefix `shop` is already present in `app.routing.ts` - you need not repeat it in `shop.routing.t`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the standard approach for lazy loading.
Use separate Module for **ShopDetailComponent** and **ShopListingComponent** and also, separate RoutingModules. Finally, consume them in LayoutModule.

**BTW, solution for your current problem:**
use **FormsModule** in your shop.module.ts file, like

```
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms'; //-------- (new line)  
 @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        GlobalModule,
        SlickModule.forRoot(),
        NouisliderModule,
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}),
        RouterModule.forChild(ShopRoutes),
        FormsModule   //-------------Add this FormsModule (new line)
      ],
      declarations: [
        ShopListingComponent,
        ShopDetailComponent  //I newly put this one.
      ],
      providers: [
        ShopService
      ]
    })
    export class ShopModule { }
```

If the issue still persists, then do let me know. There may various other reasons that we need to solve, but hopefully, this updation will solve your problem.

**Note:** even if browser page is blank, you can still see error in console.